# sql join on join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

transactions table (1 row --> 1 transaction)

```
customer_code amount
A0BEFG        100
DEC21A        80
```

payment table (1 row --> 1 transaction)

```
customer_id   payment_type
1             cash
2             credit_card
```

customer table (1 row --> 1 customer_code)

```
customer_code    customer_id
A0BEFG           2
DEC21A           1
```

Expected output:
combined table

```
customer_code customer_id amount payment_type
AOBEFG        2           100    credit_card
DEC21A        1           80     cash
```

In words, my idea is to get the payment_type into the transactions table, but because there is no matching variable, I need to first merge payment table and customer table, before connecting them to the transactions table.

Code I've tried:

```
  with 
        connection as (
        select c.customer_code, c.customer_id, p. payment_type
        from data.payment p
        left join data.customer c on p.customer_id = c.customer_id 
    ),
        transactions as (
        select t.merchant_code, t.amount
        from data.transactions t
        )
    select 
        t.merchant_code, c.customer_id, c.amount, p.payment_type 
    from transactions as t
```

Code is for PostgreSQL.

Comment: merchant_code should be overwritten with customer_code. But that does not achieve the goal

Comment: customer_code  and  customer_id from customer table are the links to the other 2 tables. What is the problem?

Comment: i cannot merge payment table and transactions table directly because customer_code is not equal customer_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join `customer` to the other tables like this:

```
SELECT c.customer_code, c.customer_id, t.amount, p.payment_type
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN customer c ON t.customer_code = c.customer_code
INNER JOIN payment p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=16703caefeecf2ab88b9dc6829d818ec).
Results:

| customer_code | customer_id | amount | payment_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0BEFG | 2 | 100 | credit_card |
| DEC21A | 1 | 80 | cash |

Comment: should i better use inner join and inner join, or left join and right join?

Comment: @Luc You should use LEFT join(s) only if there is a case that any of the tables may not contain a corresponding row that you want and it also depends on which table will be the LEFT table from which you will start the joins

Comment: I edited the code to start the joins from `transactions`. You may change the joins to LEFT joins if you see that you don't get a transaction because there is no corresponding row in the other tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.customer_code, c.customer_id, t.amount, p.payment_type
FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN payment AS p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON t.customer_code = c.customer_code
```